# Could it be that the google url shortening api key works only on 1 computer?

Tags: asp.net, url-shortener, google-url-shortener

I'm using the Google URL Shortener from an ASP.NET website. It works
fine from my localhost, but on the test server I get the following
error:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403)
Forbidden.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at GoogleUrlShortnerApi.Shorten(String url)
```

I'm using the exact code that is shown here:
http://www.jphellemons.nl/post/Google-URL-shortener-API-%28googl%29-C-sharp-class-C.aspx

Could it be that the key works only on my local computer, and not any other computer? I have obtained another key (using another Google account), but this one gives me the same error (403) both on my local computer, and on the test server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few modifications, according to a [tutorial by Scott Mitchell](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Creating-Shortened-URLs.aspx), and I change the following lines of code:

**First,** Instead of:

```
string post = "{\"longUrl\": \"" + url + "\"}";
```

I used:

```
string post = string.Format(@"{{""longUrl"": ""{0}""}}", url );
```

**Second**, I commented out these 2 lines:

```
request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;  
request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

I don't know why, but suddenly it started working. So I wanted to see which of the 3 thins I did made the problem, so I returned each one, and - TADA - it still works, even with all 3 back there! So I really don't know what caused the problem, but since the code work without those 2 commented out lines, and the other modification, I am leaving it that way.

I hope this answer will help someone sometime...

Comment: Did you called this from codebehind in page load? how did you call the method anyway?

Comment: @hsobhy This is a question from 5 years ago. I don't remember its details any more... Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt very much the API is linked to a particular PC. You need to check the requests - both the URL and headers - that your program is sending out, they must be different in some way. Is your server behind some kind of proxy - e.g Apache? If not configured right this might also be mangling the request. Also make sure your requests are encoded correctly.